# Rank a value compared to a Pandas column

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas, rank

I wish to find the rank, and percentage rank of a value, compared to a pandas column. The value is not in the pandas column, and since I am looking for a faster way of proceeding, it might not be a good idea to go down that avenue. Here is my code:

```
sqla  = ("SELECT col FROM table") #25000 rows in each table
df    = psql.read_sql(sqla, conn)

#df as np array
arr   = np.array(df['col'])

#number to rank
rank_this = 1.23456

#insert the value into arr
arr_insert = np.insert(arr,1,rank_this,axis=None)

#sort arr_insert
sorted_array = np.sort(arr_insert)

#find the position of 'rank_this' in 'sorted_array'
position = float([i for i,k in enumerate(sorted_array) if k == rank_this])

#find percentage rank of that value compared to list
foo = (1-(1-round(position/len(sorted_array),6)))*100
```

As you will probably be thinking, it's slow: it needs to run a few million times too, I am not going into Cython territory or anything too time consuming, but more Pandas definitely. Thanks for  any suggestions in advance.

Comment: @unutbu Each SQL array is 25000 rows, and for each iteration, we also select a new table. So for iteration 1 we would look up table1, for iteration 2 we use table2 etc. So no, they are all independent searches. Each 'rank_this' value searches it's own SQL table.

Comment: Is your original column already sorted or have you considered using 'ORDER BY' in the sql?

Comment: @Cyb3rFly3r It won't matter, I need to sort it with the new value inserted. Hence I will end up sorting it twice.

Comment: Communication between the database and Python may be a bottleneck. It may be more efficient to craft SQL to do the computation in the database instead of transferring a lot of data into Python and doing the computation in Python. That way, only 2 numbers need to be returned as output instead of a 25000 row DataFrame.

Comment: @unutbu Think I am going to construct one DataFrame of the 200 SQL tables with an identifier column on the DataFrame, then take slices inside a loop. Even with that, I would still be at odds sorting the column and ranking the value. It will give me something to do, thanks for suggestions.